# Remove Sharepoint RadioButtonChoiceField Focus on application page

Tags: asp.net, wss-3.0, development, application-pages

I have an application page with a bunch of asp textbox controls and then a sharepoint RadioButtonChoiceField control. When the page loads it will always set focus to the RadioButtonChoiceField is there anyway to make it focus on my 1st text box

I've tried page.setfocus(textbox.clientID), onLoad but it still goes to the radiobutton.

Answer (score 1):

```
<SCRIPT language=Javascript>     
    function WebForm_AutoFocus(focusId) {
       // alert(focusId);     
    } 
</SCRIPT>
```

Added this to the page and it doesn't scroll down to the radio button, but you can no longer set focus either.

Answer (score 0):

jquery got a nice tools to make this kind of stuff... watch this link dude.

http://mundogeek.net/archivos/2010/04/21/tutorial-rapido-de-jquery/

Comment: And the info on the page is in Spanish.